# Save position on site after postBack in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

Is there any easy way to save users position on the site after postback ?

using `maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"` in my web.config pages section doesnt work.

I mean it does work but only in ie. Is there any way to make it work on firefox and chrome ?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.kodergurl.com/2010/08/maintain-scroll-position-on-post-back.html

Comment: @jlg - Maybe you should post that as an answer. I haven't personally tested it, but it looks promising.  I'm bookmarking it to try for our site.

Comment: Ok, I try not to post links as answers because I'm not completely sure they will work. Plus it gives someone who has had that issue a chance to post what they have tried as well. :)

Comment: One thing may I know, how do any one get a up vote just after posting his/her answer? I see some person get up vote so quickly, only delay is to posting the answer by the poster! Amazing....!!! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Koder Gurl had the same type of problem back in 2010. She posted the code that was giving her trouble and from the sounds of it, she had the browser issues you are having.

Try looking at her solution at this page: http://www.kodergurl.com/2010/08/maintain-scroll-position-on-post-back.html

I hope that will help you.

Comment: One thing may I know, how do any one get a up vote just after posting his/her answer? I see some person get up vote so quickly, only delay is to posting the answer by the poster! Amazing....!!! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ive used code from the site. Works great. Ive just changed scrolledY = document.documentElement.scrollTop; to window.pageYOffset and removed section checking version because i had js errors.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in different ways as below:

a. Set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` property to true in Page directive for specific page(s).

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
      CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" 
      MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

b. For whole site, add below section to web.config file.

```
<configuration>  
   <system.web>  
      <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />  
   </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: The original question states that they are already using "maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack" and is only working for them in IE.

Comment: I've tested in different version of browsers, can try alternate way ( like changing at web.config file).
They may have some JS/CSS which is not browser compitable!

Above is the standard way and has no browser issue as I've used in several applications. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Understood. However, answering a question by repeating something that the original question said they already tried and doesn't work doesn't do much to help them. If you do think there could be a JS/CSS issue, what do you suggest they specifically look into? What alternate methods do you suggest they try, other than what they already stated?